# How to make a rotation in a object in two directions but one at a time in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, quaternions

I want to rotate the wheels of a car in two directions, up when the car is moving forward and when it's moving in the left/right direction. But, when I'm try to move the wheels after rotate left/right, the rotation still apllys in the up direction, creating a strange circular movement. I did using

```js
// to rotate in the Y axis
if (keyboard.pressed("left")) {
  wheel.rotation.y -= 0.01
}

if (keyboard.pressed("up")) {
// to rotate in the X axis
  wheel.rotation.x -= 50
}
```

[Image of the car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGz2o.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound silly, but have you tried using the 'z' axis instead of the 'y'?